# Having issues trying to get downloadURL for multiple images from firebase storage using angular fire2

Tags: firebase, frontend, angular6

I have created a collection that holds the news title, news img, news desc, etc.. I also created the upload method that works fine , uploads the file to storage and saves the path to the collection.

Issues when trying to retrieve the image using getDownloadUrl();

Here are the files

news.component.html

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div *ngFor="let item of thenews | async">


        <p>
            {{ item.newsTitle }} {{ item.newsDesc }}
        </p>


        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img [src]="getImgUrl(item.newsImg)" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="onLogout()">Logout</button>

    </div>
```

News.component.ts

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';

import { AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './../auth.service';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';

import { News } from './../models/newsModel';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news.component.css']
})

@Injectable()

export class NewsComponent implements OnInit {

  news = {} as News;
  newsCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<News>;
  thenews: Observable<News[]>;
  imgUrl: Observable<any>;
  theData: News[] = [];


  constructor(public authservice: AuthService, public dataservice: DataService, public afs: AngularFirestore,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newsCol = this.afs.collection<News>('news');
    this.thenews = this.newsCol.valueChanges();
  }

  getImgUrl(img) {
    return this.storage.ref(img).getDownloadURL();
  }


  addNews(news) {
    this.dataservice.addNews(news);
  }


  onLogout() {
    this.authservice.onLogout();
  }

}
```

When this is served it runs into an infinite loop. and the site goes hung. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**getDownloadURL**() is a **observable** method (async function), so you have to wait for the observable to return the value i.e. the url or null if the image is not available

for example

```
imageUrl: Observable<string | null>;
const ref = this.storage.ref('users/davideast.jpg');
this.imageUrl= ref.getDownloadURL();
```

in template

```
<img [src]="profileUrl | async" />
```

[Please refer this link from github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#downloading-files)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is am calling the images using ngfor in the html file. so how do i dynamically pass that image value of each iteration to the typescript file?

Comment: No you have to download all image first then pass the array into ngFor